# ¿ Como puedo Retornar una Lista Que acabo de Convertir de un Hashmap?

Tags: java, json, array

Este es mi codigo java donde convierto en Json en una lista ¿pero cuado trato de retornar la lista no funciona? PD: soy nuevo cualquier ayuda la agradeceria

```java
    private Map<String,String> construirMapDepartamentos(String jsonCiudades) {

        Map<String , String> departamentos = new HashMap<>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonCiudades);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject ciudad = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (ciudad.getJSONObject("departamento").getJSONObject("pais").optString("cdIso").toString().equals("CO")) {
                 departamentos.put(ciudad.getJSONObject("departamento").optString("cdIso"),ciudad.getJSONObject("departamento").optString("dsNombre"));
                 List <Entry> KeyList = new ArrayList<Entry>(departamentos.entrySet());
                 for(Entry tem: KeyList ) {
                     System.out.println(tem);
                 }
            }
        }
        return departamentos;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas realizando una comparación en la cual defines que si el objeto "pais" es igual a "CO" agregue al MAP departamentos los valores.

```
 if (ciudad.getJSONObject("departamento").getJSONObject("pais").optString("cdIso").toString().equals("CO")) {
 ...
 ...
```

pero el problema se debe a que cuando tratas de agregar valores, estos no existen, realiza el siguiente cambio para obtener el valor de "pais" y agregarlo al MAP:

```
 //departamentos.put(ciudad.getJSONObject("departamento").optString("cdIso"),ciudad.getJSONObject("departamento").optString("dsNombre"));
 departamentos.put("pais",ciudad.getJSONObject("departamento").getJSONObject("pais").optString("dsNombre"));
```